# How to instantiate a Kotlin generic

Tags: generics, instantiation, kotlin

In Kotlin, how do one instantiate a generic?  In C# and Java this task is very simple and I feel really stupid for not being able to do this in any way I have tried.

Note that I have no control over the derivation of the "underlying" Kotlin generic and hence cannot use variance; that which I can however guarantee is that it is an instantiable Kotlin class (not Java) which does have a zero argument constructor.

Also note that I have read this already (without getting it to work): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6728

A bit of opinion - really really like Kotlin after a week or two's play.

C# Code / a very simple example.  Java is very similar:

```cs
using System;

namespace GenInstance
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");

            var w = new Instancer<Whatever> ().Map ();
            Console.WriteLine (w);
            Console.ReadLine ();
        }
    }

    public class Instancer<T> where T : new() {
        public T Map() {
            return new T();
        }
    }

    public class Whatever {
        public override string ToString ()
        {
            return "My Instance";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "In C# and Java this task is very simple"? Can you please show a code example?

Comment: Having trouble to enter the code.

Comment: Ouch.  It is hard to believe that something this elementary and critical is not yet implemented.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not possible for free on the JVM because generic types are not reified at runtime, so I'm not sure how would you do that in Java.

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov what about your last comment in KT-6728? Isn't that the thing? 
`inline fun <reified T : Any> create(): T = T::class.primaryConstructor!!.call()`

Comment: That is using runtime reflection, which is not "for free" as it is in C# where generic types are reified and which I think the original question was about